# Нужна помощь с html и css

Tags: html, css

[image: Скриншот желаемого результата]

Всем привет, нужна помощь в разрешение проблемы. Не понимаю как сделать так чтобы синий кружок становился на место, в котором он стоит на скриншоте. Но у меня выходит что-то не то. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

---

```css
body
{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: Arial;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container
{
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 1180px;
}

.header
{
 margin-top: 1572px;
 height: 424px;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.reviews
{
 padding-top: 50px;
 margin-left: 46.1%;
 color: #445161;
 font-size: 30px;
}

.cir1
{
 display: block;
 padding-top: 25px;
}

.cloud1
{

}

.cir2
{
 
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="header">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="reviews">
     Reviews
    </div>

    <img src="images/circle.png" class="cir1">
    <img src="images/cloud.png" class="cloud1">
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
```

Вот что выходит:

[image: результат]

Comment: код Вашей попытки приложите, пожалуйста.

Comment: '.cir1
{
 display: block;
 padding-top: 25px;
}'

Comment: в теле вопроса и хотелось бы видеть не один класс, а верстку всего блока

Answer (score 2):

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 44%;
}

.circle {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100" alt="" class="circle">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur aut nihil dignissimos libero quod.</p>

  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100" alt="" class="circle">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur aut nihil dignissimos libero quod.</p>

  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100" alt="" class="circle">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur aut nihil dignissimos libero quod.</p>

  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100" alt="" class="circle">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur aut nihil dignissimos libero quod.</p>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Старайтесь, пожалуйста не только прикладывать код, но и пояснять в чем заключается идея Вашего решения, что не учел автор вопроса в своей попытке и т.д. Важно часто не столько само фактическое решение, сколько его объяснение.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте задать кружку и облаку свойства display: inline-block

```css
.cir1, .cloud1 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```